# Error Deploying Nodejs,express with typescirpt app on Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, vercel

How do I deploy a Nodejs, Express.js with Typescript app on Vercel? It's giving me an error "404: NOT_FOUND" , My index.ts file is there inside my src folder. What is the proper way to do this?

vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "src/index.ts",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/"
      }
    ]
  }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.9",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.5.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.5.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Andy Ah! I have multiple nodejs express apps running on Vercel, But this time I'm trying to deploy a ts app. i already saw the docs etc

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your vercel.json, you didn't specify the path destination (you put '/', instead it should be 'index.ts')

```js
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      // Specify the paths' destination
      "dest": "index.ts"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi! i made this same error again, Can you please check the edited post you can see my folder structure.

Comment: can you share the content of index.ts

Comment: Stackoverflow gives me errors for alot of code in my post, but the code is correct working in my local machine